# Functions over $R$ such that $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ then show that $f(x) = x^t$ for some t](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/if-fxy-fxfy-then-show-that-fx-xt-for-some-t)
>   [Solution for exponential function's functional equation by using a definition of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64766/solution-for-exponential-functions-functional-equation-by-using-a-definition-of)

I can think of three functions that satisfy the condition $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y$, namely

- $f(x) = x$
- $f(x) = 0$
- $f(x) = 1$

Are there more?

And is there a good way to prove that such a list is exhaustive (once expanded to include any other examples that I haven't thought of)?

Comment: $f(x) = |x|^a$ for any constant $a$ will work. I think these are the only *continuous* functions $f$ satisfying this condition (but there are many other "monstrous" solutions).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43964/if-fxy-fxfy-then-show-that-fx-xt-for-some-t http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64766/solution-for-exponential-functions-functional-equation-by-using-a-definition-of

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot all about the fact that $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$. So I guess the answer to the first question is "yes", but my second question remains.

Comment: There is a term for what you are asking about, 'totally multiplicative function': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function

Comment: @Wade: That's not a good link. "Completely multiplicative function" is a term of art in number theory to refer to functions whose domain are the *positvie integers* and that are multiplicative. The very first sentence in the wikipedia page specifies that we are talking about functions "of positive integers".

Answer (score 10):

Since $f(x) = f(1)f(x)$ for all $x$, either $f(1)=1$, or else $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Assume $f(1)=1$. If $f(a)=0$ for some $a\neq 0$, then $f(b) = f(a)f(b/a) = 0$ for all $b$, so we may assume $f(a)\neq 0$ for all $a\neq 0$.

Also, $f(1) = f(-1)^2$, so either $f(-1)=1$ or $f(-1)=-1$.  If $a\gt 0$ then $f(a)=(f(\sqrt{a}))^2$, so $a\gt 0$ implies $f(a)\gt 0$. Thus, if $f(-1)=-1$ then $f$ is odd on the nonzero numbers; and if $f(-1)=1$ then $f$ is even.

As for $f(0)$, since $f(0)=f(0)^2$, either $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. If $f(0)=1$, then $1=f(0) = f(0a) = f(a)$, so $f(a)=1$ for all $a$.

So we have a couple of "degenerate" solutions: $f(a)=0$ for all $a$; $f(a)=1$ for all $a$; and $f(a)=1$ for all $a\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

So now assume that $f(1)=1$, $f(0)=0$, $f(a)\gt 0$ for all $a\gt 0$.

Now consider $g(x) = \ln(f(e^x))$. Then
$$g(x+y) = \ln(f(e^{x+y})) = \ln(f(e^xe^y)) = \ln (f(e^x)f(e^y)) = \ln(f(e^x))+\ln(f(e^y)) = g(x)+g(y),$$
so $g$ satisfies [Cauchy's Functional Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Both the "even" and the "odd" version of $f$ yield the same $g$, since $g$ only depends on the values of $f$ on the positive reals.

Conversely, given any $g\neq 0$ that satisfies Cauchy's Functional Equation, define $h$ on the *positive reals* by $h(x) = \exp(g(\ln(x))$. Then $h(xy) = h(x)h(y)$, and $h(x)$ is not the constant function $1$. Letting $h(0)=0$, you obtain two functions $f$ that satisfy your original equation: $f(x) = h(|x|)$, and $f(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x)h(|x|)$.

Now, I cheated, because Cauchy's Functional Equation does not have an explicit complete list of solutions, but it's been well-studied, so you might as well look into *that* instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one more:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&\mathrm{for}& x=0,\\
1&\mathrm{for}& x\neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$