# Discontinuous function satisfying $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, exponential-function

Suppose $f$ is a function satisfying
$$
f(x)f(y)=f(x+y) \label{*}\tag{*} \\
$$
for all $x$ and $y$. If we require that $f$ be continuous, then it can be shown that $f(x)=a^x$ for some constant $a$, or $f=0$. In Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, it is mentioned that there in fact infinitely many *discontinuous* functions satisfying $\eqref{*}$. What are the most notable examples?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82480/functions-over-r-such-that-fxy-fxfy/82494#82494).

Comment: See also [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides and it will be converted into the Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: @VivaanDaga: I don't understand what allows us to take logs of both sides. That only seems to work if we are given that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. Even if we allow complex numbers to enter the mix, we still have to ensure $f(x) \neq 0$, don't we?

Comment: @Joe You can prove that if such a function is $0$ somewhere then it is $0$ everywhere so you can discard that case , also note that $f(x+x)=(f(x))^2$ which is always positive

Comment: @Joe does my answer answer your question ? Or is there still other questions ?

Comment: @VivaanDaga: Sorry, I haven't gone through your answer yet, but thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there exists a discontinuous function satisfying the Cauchy functional equation $g(x)$ ,$e^{g(x)}$ will satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $k(x)=e^{g(x)}$ must be discontinuous since composition of continuous functions are always continuous but $\ln(k(x))=g(x)$ which is discontinuous. Since there are infinitely many discontinuous functions satisfying the Cauchy functional equation there are infinitely many discontinuous functions satisfying your equation .